# WiX: keep (rename) file on uninstall

Tags: wix, uninstallation

My application has a settings file which I need to keep when user uninstalls the app. Can I do this using components, or do I need to use custom actions?

This is what I have so far (not working):

```
<Directory Id="INSTALLLOCATION" Name="_MyApp">
  <Component>
    <File KeyPath="yes" Source="$(var.Source)\settings.ini" />
  </Component>
  <Component Id="Backup" Guid="SOME-GUID">
    <Condition>REMOVE=ALL</Condition>
    <CopyFile Id="settings.ini" Delete="no" SourceProperty="INSTALLLOCATION" DestinationProperty="INSTALLLOCATION" SourceName="settings.ini" DestinationName="settings.ini.bak" />
  </Component>
</Directory>
```

If it matters, these components belong to:

```
<Feature Id="Default" Level="1">
  <ComponentRef Id="settings.ini" />
  <ComponentRef Id="Backup" />
</Feature>
```

I suspected this does not work because action MoveFiles runs after RemoveFiles and then there's nothing left to move, so I removed settings.ini from installer and copied it manually after installation. I was thinking this way the ini file is still there after RemoveFiles and it will be renamed. Well, the ini file is there indeed but it doesn't get renamed. Any idea why?

Answer (score 1):

Windows Installer doesn't have a built-in mechanism for backing up and restoring files. Usually the solution is to use a custom action which copies the file.

> I removed settings.ini from installer
>   and copied it manually after
>   installation. I was thinking this way
>   the ini file is still there after
>   RemoveFiles and it will be backed-up.
>   Well, the ini file is there indeed but
>   it doesn't get backed-up.

Try creating an uninstall log and see what happens when MoveFiles is executed. As a side note, I don't see how copying the file manually after install is better than a backup custom action.

Comment: Cosmin, thank you for your response. I might have misused the word "backup": it only means "create a copy of that file". I certainly do not intend to restore it afterwards. I edited the post to fix the misunderstanding. Regarding the log file, I did what you suggested and nothing happens on MoveFile. Maybe the component condition is wrong?

Comment: Yeah, I missed that. The condition should be REMOVE = &quot;ALL&quot;. Otherwise the "ALL" string will be treated as a property. All string values should be enclosed by quotes when dealing with properties.

Comment: Thanks, it's good to know this. Unfortunately it still does not do anything on uninstall. I wonder if the component condition is even evaluated on uninstall... assuming the code is correct, probably not.

Comment: Can you post the uninstall log somewhere so we can take a look?

Comment: Component conditions are used only to determine whether a component should be installed. They don't let you do extra things at uninstall time.

Comment: I see. I'll go for custom actions then. Thank you guys!